# HttpException: maximum request length exceeded, even when config has values that should allow it

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I can't seem to allow a 4.3MB upload. I keep getting this error:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length
>   exceeded.

My web.config settings in my Web API:

```
<!-- maxRequestLength expresses POST buffer size in KB. This is the ASP.NET limit. -->
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="20000" />

<!-- Let this be larger than maxRequestLength so we get ASP.NET error (if request too large) instead of IIS error. -->
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20480000" />
```

And this is the call to the API from my web project:

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(proxyRequest);
```

That always returns the above error. What am I missing? I did read where `maxRequestLength` needs to be the same value as `maxAllowedContentLength`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is it that the error occurs in the client (and not on the server)?

Comment: The browser sends the request to our web controller. Then, our web controller calls our Web API. That's where the call fails.

Answer (score 0):

The "Default Web Site" in IIS had a config file with almost nothing in it. I added `maxRequestLength="20000"` to it and it worked. My app is one of many apps under "Default Web Site."

Added this:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="20000" />
  </system.web>
```